# sum Submited  Radio Buttons value in same or another page?

Tags: php

I am new in PHP and I am working on survey and database. I have two tables: one contains the questions and the other contains the answers. These 2 tables have the following attributes:

```
     _________________           _________________
    | TABLE-QUESTION  |         | TABLE-ANSWER    |
    |_________________|         |_________________|
    |  id             |         |  id             |
    |  survey_name    |         |  qid            |
    |  question       |         |  answer         |
    |  status         |         |  answer_value   |
    |_________________|         |_________________|
```

Each answer has multiple value and select with radio button

```
 <?php
      $newsurvey=$db->get_results("SELECT * FROM question where status='1' order by `id` ");
      if($newsurvey)
      {
           foreach($newsurvey as $survey1)
           {
 ?>         
                <h3><?php echo $survey1->question?></h3>

                <?php
                     $slider=$db->get_results("SELECT * FROM answer where qid='$survey1->id' ");
                     if($slider)
                     {
                          foreach($slider as $answer1)
                          {
                ?>
                               <div class="entry">
                                    <input type="radio" name='$survey1->id' value="
                                         <?php echo $answer1->answer_value?>"/>
                                    <?php echo $answer1->answer?>
                                </div>
                     <?php
                          }
                     }
                     ?>
            <?php
                 }
           }
           ?>

           <input type="Submit" value="Submit">
```

What I want is to sum and store all submitted radio buttons value in another Page.

How to do this?

Comment: Try this `<input type="radio" name='<?= 'answer_'.$survey1->id'.'[]' ?> value="<?php echo $answer1->answer_value?>"/><?php echo $answer1->answer?>`

Comment: @RHR using this only one radio button is select each time. I want to select one radio button in each question. And I want to sum the value in same page or another page. please sir help me.

Comment: you want to sum all answer value ?

Comment: @RHR Yes in answer_value field there are different value regarding the answer. Now I want to sum all the selected answer buttons(after Clicking Submit button) value in same page or another page.

Comment: @RHR This table has 2 question and 3 different answer option on each question. I want to select one option in each question. But I can able to select only one option for this 2 question.

Answer (score 0):

You could use multiple radio e.q.

```
<input type="radio" name="survey[SURVEY_ID]">
```

Try store in $_SESSION for e.q.

```
$_SESSION["survey"] = $_POST["survey"]; // Under key 'survey' you have array of radio buttons
```

Comment: Its not working, I want to select one option each on each question but it select only one in all. so, please help me defining brif..

Answer (score 0):

Try this `<input type="radio" name='answer_value[]' value="<?php echo $answer1->answer_value?>"/><?php echo $answer1->answer?>`.

If you print `$_POST['answer_value']`,you will get all select values in array,using `$sum = array_sum($_POST['answer_value'])` to sum all selected values...

Comment: This table has 2 question and 3 different answer option on each question. I want to select one option in each question. But I can able to select only one option for this 2 question.